# mySQL query not returning dates

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, state, DATE_FORMAT( '%m/%d', registered ) AS date_formatted
FROM users
WHERE CAST( registered AS DATE ) > DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY state, date_formatted
```

Above is our query we are using to return information from our database.

Our dates are saved as: `2011-03-28 14:36:48` (datetime field)

The data being returned is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [act] => 1
            [nsw] => 1
            [nt] => 1
            [qld] => 3
            [sa] => 1
            [tas] => 1
            [vic] => 1
            [wa] => 4
        )

)
```

And it isn't returning the date in the array.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) { $my_array[$row['date_formatted']][$row['state']] = $row['count']; }
```

Here is the php code we are using to form the array.

Thanks :)

Comment: I cannot believe that for query with 3 expressions in `SELECT` clause you get 8 values in php. It is just impossible. PS: `CAST( registered AS DATE )` casting here is pointless and declines the possibility of using indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) takes the date as the first argument, and the format as the second argument:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, state, DATE_FORMAT(registered ,'%m/%d')
...
```